# while i inserted a new empty white space div before or after the current selected div,suddenly the tabs Height is increased in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, mouseevent

My project is create an google module tab application.IT contains 5  tabs normally. if i click on first tab,an empty space li follow the current selected list by insertbefore().by this i face an problem...the 
5 tabs inside the tabs  container.
if an empty list is created. the tabs height is increased. i think an small problem in css property..
Note: the Tab container is viewed as background color of LightGrey

[this image contains normal view and after viewing of click events](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B152qvIDXPwLdk1vdktYMHlIYzA)

Note:-

this project contains I.html  this is the main code file

[here i am uploaded the shareable link of my project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B152qvIDXPwLdk1vdktYMHlIYzA)

Comment: great , now can you provide the email and password of your gmail account so we can see the file :)

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `font-size: 0` on elements to stop this from happening.

Alternatively, you can set `display: block` so that the browser doesn't treat the element as text.